# How does four variable swapping work in Lua?

Tags: lua

hello I have this activity in lua:
Enter data into 4 different variables (A, B, C, and D). Place the contents of A in C, that of C in B, that of B in D and that of D in A. Show the new order of contents. Don't lose the original data.
but I don't know how to do it
could you help me?

Comment: this sounds like homework. the whole point of exercises like that is that you think and research yourself. asking for a solution defeats the purpose of any programming exercise. you should instead read the Lua manual where you would find a solution in Chapter 3. if you start at the beginning that's less than 15 minutes of reading and taking notes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way to accomplish swapping values in lua is to use multiple assignments.

[Programming in Lua: 4.1 – Assignment](https://www.lua.org/pil/4.1.html)

> In a multiple assignment, Lua first evaluates all values and only then executes the assignments. Therefore, we can use a multiple assignment to swap two values, as in
>
> ```
>  x, y = y, x                -- swap `x' for `y'`
> ```

For your case it would look like this:

```
a, b, c, d = d, c, a, b
```

---

You can also find similar information in the Lua reference manual

[Lua Reference Manual: 3.3.3 – Assignment](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.3.3):

> The assignment statement first evaluates all its expressions and only then the assignments are performed. Thus the code
>
> ```
>     i = 3
>     i, a[i] = i+1, 20
> ```
>
> sets a[3] to 20, without affecting a[4] because the i in a[i] is evaluated (to 3) before it is assigned 4. Similarly, the line
>
> ```
>     x, y = y, x
> ```
>
> exchanges the values of x and y, and
>
> ```
>     x, y, z = y, z, x
> ```
>
> cyclically permutes the values of x, y, and z.

---

If you are new to lua the book [Programming in Lua](https://www.lua.org/pil/contents.html) is an excellent resource for items like this. I encourage you to give it a read, it is a very well written guide to lua.